# proving $a_0(q)= \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-q^{2n})$ from ratio equation $\frac{a_0(q)}{a_0(q^4)} = \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(1-q^{2n})}{(1-q^{8n})}$

Tags: products, infinite-product

I want to prove $a_0(q)= \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-q^{2n})$ 
fromo following relation 
\begin{align}
  \frac{a_0(q)}{a_0(q^4)} = \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(1-q^{2n})}{(1-q^{8n})}
\end{align}
with inital condition $a_0(0)=1$.

Now from the cross ratio 
\begin{align}
  \frac{a_0(q)}{\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-q^{2n})} =   \frac{a_0(q^4)}{\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-q^{8n})} = \cdots =  \frac{a_0(q^{4^k})}{\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-q^{2\times 4^k n})}
\end{align}

The textbook says this shows $a_0(q) = \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-q^{2n})$ but I have no idea why this is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For integers $k\ge0$ and $|q|<1$, $$\frac{a_0(q)}{a_0\left(q^{4^{k+1}}\right)}=\prod_{j=0}^k\frac{a_0\left(q^{4^j}\right)}{a_0\left(q^{4^{j+1}}\right)}=\prod_{j=0}^k\prod_{n\ge1}\frac{1-q^{n2^{2j+1}}}{1-q^{n2^{2j+3}}}=\prod_{n\ge1}\prod_{j=0}^k\frac{1-q^{n2^{2j+1}}}{1-q^{n2^{2j+3}}}=\prod_{n\ge1}\frac{1-q^{2n}}{1-q^{2^{2k+3}n}}.$$I think you also need to assume continuity in a neighbourhood of $q=0$. Taking $k\to\infty$,$$\frac{a_0(q)}{a_0(0)}=\prod_{n\ge1}(1-q^{2n}).$$

Comment: Thanks, I noticed what I missed. Since $|q|<1$, $q^{\infty} \rightarrow 0$!. That is what I missed! Thanks for the clarification.